# is this a bug? please check it out

Tags: javascript, jquery

## html

```
<div contentEditable="true">testing....</div>
```

## jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('[contenteditable]').removeAttr('contenteditable');
});
```

above codes is fine and working. you can feel it [here](http://jsfiddle.net/hRR3b/).

Now, try this

```
$('[contentEditable]').removeAttr('contentEditable'); 
// notice the CamelCase of the string contentEditable
```

in FF 3.6, it gives an error on the console

> An invalid or illegal string was
>   specified" code: "12 
>  elem[ name ]
>   = value;

and the div is still editable.

I suspected it was the jQuery selector, but is not. By further inspection, it was the argument passed on the `.removeAttr('contentEditable');`. It works when all small letters. So, I thought it should be all small letters. I'm curious so I tried adding `CLass` as an attribute and do `.removeAttr('CLass');`. But then it works without error.

So, how come `contentEditable` is giving me that error?

---

## update

from Kobi, it seems that it actually accept any case except, `contentEditable` (I did try too).

[CamelCase](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CamelCase)

Comment: Is this doctype HTML5 or XHTML?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't about small letters, but about the ***exact casing***. Any other casing than `contentEditable` works, for example: `removeAttr('ConTentEditable');`.
I can't find the exact source of the problem, I guess it's a Firefox restriction.

It seems jQuery [sets the attribute to an empty string](http://james.padolsey.com/jquery/#v=1.4&fn=jQuery.fn.removeAttr) before removing it, which is what's causing the error. This seems to work better:

```
$('[contentEditable]').attr('contentEditable', false);
```

Answer (score 2):

You could call it a bug, but really the framework is designed this way.  `removeAttr`, along with other *attr* functions, points to `jQuery.attr()` to set the attribute's value.  After setting the attribute to `""`, it then attempts to remove it.  The code for `attr()` specifically checks to see if the given string is a property name on the object first using the `in` operator:

```
// If applicable, access the attribute via the DOM 0 way
if ( name in elem && notxml && !special ) {
```

(from jQuery 1.4, line 1452-1453)

Since you're supplying the camelCase property name, it uses that instead of `elem.setAttribute()`, which is specifically the cause of the problem.  For any other case, `name in elem` would return false (because property names are case sensitive), which is why it's successful then. jQuery does this mostly to work around cross browser issues with `setAttribute()`.

It looks like Firefox has a problem with setting the property to an empty string, unless you have the same problem in other browsers.  You could try and file a bug either on the jQuery site or MDC.

Comment: +1. Because of traditional IE bugs, jQuery's `attr` functions try to hide the difference between an HTML attribute (`contenteditable`) and a DOM property (`contentEditable`). With confusing results, as usual when you try to hide an important difference.

Answer (score 0):

contentEditable seams to be a special attribute:
http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/editing.html#contenteditable

Answer (score 0):

The `contentEditable` **property** (not attribute, since that isn't what `attr()` and friends usually deal with) expects a string value, one of "true", "false" and "inherit". I wouldn't use jQuery to turn off `contentEditable`, but I imagine the following would work:

```
$('[contenteditable]').attr("contentEditable", "false");
```

Or you could bypass jQuery for setting the actual `contentEditable` property:

```
$('[contenteditable]').each(function() {
    this.contentEditable = "false";
});
```